# why frames not raising with tkinter tkraise?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT=("Verdana",12)

class myClass(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container,self,"startPage","visit page 1","pageone")
        frame2 = StartPage(container,self,"pageone","Go BAck","startPage")
        self.frames["startPage"]=frame
        self.frames["pageone"]=frame2

        frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("startPage")

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        print(cont)
        print(self.frames)
        print(self.frames[cont])
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise()

def qf(param):
    print(param)

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller,lableName,butonName,visitToPage):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,text=lableName,font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self,text =butonName,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(visitToPage))
        button1.pack()



app = myClass()

app.mainloop()
```

I am trying to create two frames using one class `StartPage` so I have given arguments to `StartPage` for frame 1 is `"startPage"`,`"visit page 1"`,`"pageone"` and for frame 2 is `"pageone"`,`"Go BAck"`,`"startPage"`,
but by pressing button frames are not switching even though arguments are correct to function `show_frame`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't working because you haven't placed the pageone frame in the grid. Just put this line after frame.grid and it works:

```
frame2.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
```